# Que linguagem tem melhor performance para o webcrawler multithread utilizando paralelismo

Tags: java, python, aplicação-web

Vou começar um projecto em que uma das fases vai buscar determinadas informações em sites de outras empresas.

Tendo em conta que o [`webcrawler`](https://www.webcrawler.com/) vai percorrer `x` sites, e em cada site vai visitar várias páginas pelo menos uma vez por dia, talvez seja interessante ter um Webcrawler `multithread`, usando o paralelismo para acelerar o processo.

Neste ponto, não sei se o Python tem a mesma resposta que o Java.

#### Pergunta:

Dadas as ferramentas que cada um de nós dispõe, **o que a experiência demonstra ser** a melhor opção a nível de performance, Java ou Pyhthon? Neste ponto, o Python fica a perder em relação ao Java?

Comment: Apesar da edição a pergunta ainda sim é off-topic, pois se baseia em opiniões. Porém mesmo não podendo fornecer uma resposta, vou tentar lhe deixar com a mente mais aberta sobre isto. A linguagem em si não vai necessariamente ser uma melhor que a outra, o que eu acredito que pode melhorar a perfomance é a lib que usará para baixar as páginas, a capacidade do teu server e a estrutura do teu algorítimo. No entanto a sua duvida focada apenas nos Threads pode ser respondida se a pergunta for algo como "Como funciona as threads em python e java?", então a partir das respostas você poderia testar...

Comment: ...Qual tem melhor "performance" em teu server. Acredito que a unica coisa que irá mudar entre ambas linguagens será realmente como os threads funcionam, fora isto todas respostas que encontrei no soen são bem antigas e realmente não achei um bom caminho considera-las. Tenho pouco conhecimento nesta área, acredito que logo alguém irá fornecer uma resposta ou comentário mais claro ou que melhor aborda o assunto.

Comment: De uma olhada no [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPv6Q_5Ctd4) do Thiago Avelino sobre como ele melhorou muito o desempenho do webcrawler dele mudando de python para Go.

Comment: Para mim esta pergunta é baseada em opiniões. A melhor resposta possível é *DEPENDE*. Depende da implementação, da rede, da quantidade de informação, etc., etc., etc. Poderia ainda argumentar que a linguagem não faz diferença, pois mesmo sem suporte à threads é possível paralelizar usando diferentes processos. Além disso, geralmente o gargalo vai estar na transferência de rede e não no processamento. Enfim, qualquer perda ou ganho de desempenho vai estar mais relacionado à arquitetura da solução do que à linguagem em si.

Comment: Uma das formas de implementar é criar uma fila de itens a ser processado em um banco de dados qualquer. Aí você inicia vários processos que ficam tirando itens da fila, baixam o conteúdo e processam. Na verdade, você pode criar diferentes processos em diferentes linguagens e usar todos ao mesmo tempo. Indo mais longe, você pode separar isso em duas fases, na primeira o processo baixa o arquivo e salva num local temporário, na segunda o conteúdo é processado. Então dá para ainda para fazer o download usando Java e o *parse* usando Python ou vice-versa. Resumo: foque na arquitetura.

Comment: Sim eu percebo que mais do que a linguagem a arquitectura é que vai optimizar o crawler. Mas dadas as api's/lib que cada uma linguagens oferece pensei que podia influenciar a escolha.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de qual ferramenta você vai usar, e isso depende de se você precisa emular um browser e se sim se você precisa emular tão bem.

Eu já escrevi muitos crawlers/webscrappers em python principalmente, apesar de terem libs como lxml que são muito rapidas o maior problema em processar o site de terceiros é html mal formado e conteudo em javascript.

No final vale a pena usar selenium, que pode usar o browser de verdade (pode usar o firefox, chrome etc).

O selenium não tem uma performace muito boa justamente porque os browsers ocupam muita memória e consomem muita CPU, o selenium em si só envia comandos para o browser que você escolheu.

Mas vale a pena porque ele vai executar o javascript exatamente como ele foi testado e vai funcionar como se uma pessoa estivesse usando, se a informação que você precisa é visível ao usuário então você tem como acessa-la com o selenium.

O selenium tem bindings para várias linguages incluindo python a java, voce pode escrever o seu codigo em qualquer uma das duas, no final a melhor é a que você conhece melhor ou é mais produtivo.